# Evaluate : $\lim_{n\to \infty}\{(1+\frac{1}{2n})(1+\frac{3}{2n})(1+\frac{5}{2n})\cdots (1+\frac{2n-1}{2n})\}^{\frac{1}{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate : $\lim_{n\to \infty}\{(1+\frac{1}{2n})(1+\frac{3}{2n})(1+\frac{5}{2n})\cdots (1+\frac{2n-1}{2n})\}^{\frac{1}{2n}}$

My attempt : Since, [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n^{1/n} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$]
$$Here \ \ a_n = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(1+\frac{2k-1}{2n}\right) $$
I got $$\frac{ a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(4n+1)(4n+3)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)\times (1+\frac{1}{n})^n}$$
$$\ Hence, \ \lim\limits _{n\to \infty} {\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}}=\frac{4}{e} $$

My question is can I still use Cauchy's second theorem if the power of the function is $\frac{1}{2n}$? Caused I've solved it same as the power  $\frac{1}{n}$. Please help me for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So,the answer should be the square root of what you got.

Comment: As well as: [$\lim_{n\to \infty}\{(1+\frac{1}{2n})\cdot (1+\frac{3}{2n}) \cdot (1+\frac{5}{2n})\cdots(1+\frac{2n-1}{2n})\}^{{1}/{2n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2756497/721644)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $$x_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{2k+1}{2n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}}\quad \text{and}\quad y_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{2k}{2n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}}.$$

let $$k_n=\prod_{k=0}^{2n-1}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{2n}.$$
So, $$x_n=\frac{k_n}{y_n},$$
and you can compute $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\ln(y_n)\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{n\to \infty }\ln(k_n),$$ using Riemann sum.

Answer (score 1):

Another way
$$:L\lim_{n\to \infty}\{(1+\frac{1}{2n})(1+\frac{3}{2n})(1+\frac{5}{2n})\cdots (1+\frac{2n-1}{2n})\}^{\frac{1}{2n}}$$
$$\implies \ln L=lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{2k-1}{2n}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \ln (1+x) dx$$
Here, we use $k/n=x, 1/n \to dx$ when $n$ is very large.
$$\implies \ln L=\frac{1}{2} [(1+x)\ln(1+x)-(1+x)]_{0}^{1}=\ln 2-1/2$$
$$L=2 e^{-1/2}.$$

Comment: In the step $$\ln L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{2k-1}{2n}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \ln (1+x) dx$$  Have you taken $$\frac{2k-1}{2n}=\frac{k}{n}$$ and neglected $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, as $n$ is very large.

Comment: In that case, we are adding 0's infinite times. The sum may or may not be tending to 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are right $\ln L$ actually takes the indeterminate form $0\times \infty$, so one requires a special method of converting the limit of sum to an integral when $n\to \infty$.

Comment: What is that method may I ask?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n)= \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$ $k/n=x$ and $1/n \to dx$, sum is changed to integral..

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. I know that $$\int_0^1{f(x)dx}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{f(\frac{k}{n})}$$ In this case we have  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{2k-1}{2n}\right)$$ But $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1{ln(1+x)dx}$ and  not $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{k}{n}\-frac{1}{n}right=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1{ln(1+x)dx}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111975/discussion-between-datboi-and-dr-zafar-ahmed-dsc).